# How do I change this to check for and replace NANS with a value. Also I need to fill blank parts in rows and columns

Tags: c++

I have a data-set with many rows and columns of values, how do I check the code for NAN and replace them with a value and fill any blank spaces with "00"?

I've read the file and the data is organized orderly into columns so I want to replace the NANS, add up the totals of the rows and columns  then find the averages, max and min.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


int const number_of_columns = 25; // declares number of columbs of type int and a constant value

// creating a string array for names of columns
string column_names[number_of_columns] = {
    "Date Time",
    "Year",
    "Month",
    "Day",
    "Time",
    "Data Quality",
    "Temperature",
    "Temp Flag",
    "Dew Point Temp Flag",
    "Rel Hum Flag",
    "Wind Dir Flag",
    "Dew Point",
    "Rel Hum",
    "Wind Dir",
    "Wind Spd",
    "Wind Spd Flag",
    "Visibility",
    "Visibility Flag",
    "Stn Press",
    "Stn Press Flag",
    "Hmdx",
    "Hmdx Flag",
    "Wind Chill",
    "Weather"
};


struct Row
{
    string columns[number_of_columns];
};

int main() {
    // reading data from a string
    ifstream myfile("C:\\Users\\kaileba\\Downloads\\WindEnergy\\data.dat");
    ofstream Output;

    if (myfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "There seems to have been an error!, Good Bye!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        vector<Row> rows;
        string line;
        int row_index = 0;

        //Read rows from file and store in a vector for later use
        while (getline(myfile, line)) {
            stringstream linestream(line);
            string data;

            //create a new row struct and insert into the rows vector
            rows.push_back(Row());
            int col_index = 0;
            while (getline(linestream, data, '\t')) {

                rows[row_index].columns[col_index] = data;
                col_index += 1;

                // if last piece of data increase the row index
                if (data.compare("NA") == 0) {
                    row_index += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        //Open file so we can read to
        Output.open("Results.txt");

        //Get the number of rows in the vector
        int number_of_rows = rows.size();

        //Output all column names
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_columns; i++)
        {
            if (column_names[i].compare("Weather") == 0) {
                cout << column_names[i];
                Output << column_names[i];
            }
            else {
                cout << column_names[i] << "\t";
                Output << column_names[i] << "\t";
            }
        }

        // Output all rows data
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++)
        {
            string temp_str = "";

            for (int j = 0; j < number_of_columns; j++)
            {
                if (rows[i].columns[j].compare("NA") == 0)
                    temp_str += rows[i].columns[j];
                else
                    temp_str += rows[i].columns[j] + "\t";
            }


        cout << temp_str << "\n";
            Output << temp_str << "\n";
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: replace `rows.push_back(Row());` with `Row temp;` Then you can  `temp.columns[col_index] = data;` and `rows.push_back(temp);` after the `while (getline...)` loop. Eliminates the need for `row_index` and `if (data.compare("NA") == 0)`

Comment: the rows.push_back(Row()) is for the vector

Comment: Rows doesn't care if you push the `Row` in before or after. It just turns out there is a lot of extra overhead in pushing the `Row` in before as opposed to after. Also great readability benefits to adding a constructor and `operator[]` to `Row`. Example: http://ideone.com/tmS2Wz

Comment: On the other hand, using a vector in a vector has serious performance drawbacks due to poor spatial locality, so take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: I would like to make it much simpler but it was recommended to uses vectors since I don't know the amount of rows...there's like over 300 rows and about 25 columns

Comment: My last comment was unclear. A vector contains a pointer to its data, so if you have a vector that contains an array you wind up with one long block of data and modern CPUs love big long runs of data. It can load up the cache and really speed along. But if you have a vector that contains another vector, which I suggested in the code I linked, you effectively have one block of data that points at other blocks of data and the CPU winds up hopping around in memory and can't load as effectively.

Comment: So one of the things I suggested makes the program easier to write, but perform a lot worse that what you have with the vector with an array in it.